# Select multiple instances of a record

Tags: sql, intersystems-cache

I have a spreadsheet with a long list of identifiers and various other data.  I have a column on the spreadsheet for another identifier that I need to fill in.  Here is an example of what it looks like:

```
ID1  |  ID2  |  Date
5    |       |  ...
6    |       |  ...
6    |       |  ...
7    |       |  ...
9    |       |  ...
9    |       |  ...
9    |       |  ...
10   |       |  ...
10   |       |  ...
11   |       |  ...
```

I need to get ID2 from a table in a database.  I can easily copy the ID1 column and use a text editor to replace `\r\n` with `','` then run `SELECT ID1, ID2 FROM MyTable WHERE ID1 IN ('5,6,6,7,9,9,9,10,10,11')`  The problem is that the results only show unique values for ID1 which means I would have to go through the spreadsheet and paste the values manually.  Instead, what I want is the following results:

```
ID1  |  ID2  |  Date
5    |   a   |  ...
6    |   b   |  ...
6    |   b   |  ...
7    |   c   |  ...
9    |   e   |  ...
9    |   e   |  ...
9    |   e   |  ...
10   |   f   |  ...
10   |   f   |  ...
11   |   g   |  ...
```

That way I can copy and paste into the spreadsheet and all the rows will line up properly.

I tried doing something like this:

```
SELECT ID1, ID2 FROM MyTable a, ('5','6','6',...) b
```

But that doesn't seem to work.  I have no idea what else to try.

Comment: Do you have another column that you can use to uniquely identify each row?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: For the ID2 column, when you look it up, you are looking it up based on the value that is in the ID1 column?

Comment: Yes, see the inline `SELECT` statement

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, why not load your spreadsheet into a database table.  Then use a subselect for the column.

Comment: To expand on @Jay's solution, just copy your first 2 columns (the second column empty) into a table and do your update on the server.  The database has no way of knowing how many times you want a row duplicated, even when you duplicate the value in your `IN()` list.

Answer (score 0):

Going to attempt to answer this based on what I am grasping from your question.  I'm also assuming SQL Server here.

You should upload your existing spreadsheet to a database table, let's call that table OriginalTable.  Now you have the Original Table that looks like this:

```
ID1  |  ID2  |  Date
5    |       |  ...
6    |       |  ...
6    |       |  ...
7    |       |  ...
9    |       |  ...
9    |       |  ...
9    |       |  ...
10   |       |  ...
10   |       |  ...
11   |       |  ...
```

Next, I'm assuming you have a table that has the corresponding ID2s for each ID1.  Let's assume that table is called IDTable.  May look something like this:

```
ID1  |  ID2 
5    |  a 
6    |  b
7    |  c   
9    |  e      
10   |  f        
11   |  g
```

Lastly, run a query like this:

```
SELECT Orig.ID1, (SELECT IDT.ID2 FROM IDTable IDT WHERE IDT.ID1 = Orig.ID1) AS ID2, Orig.Date
FROM OriginalTable Orig
```

Comment: Unfortunately creating a table isn't an option.  Unless you're talking about a temporary table, in which case I'm not sure that is an option in [tag:intersystems-cache].